Can I bind with numbers in the binding, d{n}c to d{n}l for example?
I am trying to bind my keys in such a way that if I press d, then a number, and then c it deletes that number of characters, like d, number, l would do.
So for example if I press d5c it would do d5l. I could just bind all combinations, but then it would not work for for example d15c.
What would be the best way to do this?
( I am running nvim btw, may that help )

Welcome to Vim :-) Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I would do:
onoremap c l

The important aspect here is that after hitting d Vim is in the Operator Pending mode.
You can control the mapping in Operator Pending mode using the onoremap or the omap commands.

Ah, thank you. This helps! I noticed the 'Operator Pending' text instead of the usual 'Insert', 'Normal', or 'Visual' in my statusline, but this explains what it is.

Thank you for the feedback :-)
